# Payments not processing stripe checkout nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

My payments are not processing through stripe, I have everything set up the way I want, and stripe actually redirects to the success page I have set, after I enter the credit card details, etc. but the problem is, it is not actually processing the request. I go into the stripe dashboard, and it shows that there hasn't been activity since yesterday, and that no new payments have been processed, cancelled, or incomplete. I would also get an email from stripe as a payment receipt if the payment went through, but nothing. The code is below (apologies for the messy code)

index.js (backend NODEJS code)

```
 app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {

    var amount = stringify(req.body)
    console.log(req.body.sessionID)
    var userId = req.body.sessionID
    console.log("email: " + req.body.deliveryDate)
    var email = req.body.customer_email;
    var deliveryTotal = req.body.totalWithDelivery;
    var totalVal = amount.split("=");
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(totalVal[1]);
    //console.log("TOTAL PRICE: " + totalPrice);
    var finalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100);
  
    var finalTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100) + parseFloat(Math.round(deliveryTotal));
    console.log("final total: " + finalTotal);
    var itemName = ""
    var itemPrice = ""
    var totalNewPriceTest = ""

    //defining arrays
    var productsArray = [];
    var priceArray = [];
    //query to database
  
    var productsStripe = "select * from " + userId
    console.log(userId)
    console.log("query to db for displaying cart on stripe page")
    ibmdb.open("DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-14.services.dal.bluemix.net;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=;PWD=", function (err,conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
      conn.query(productsStripe,  async function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(rows)
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        //   itemName = rows[i]['ITEM']
        //   itemPrice = rows[i]['PRICE']
          totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(rows[i]['PRICE'])
          console.log("item name : " + itemName + " " + itemPrice )
          totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest);
          console.log("final overall prcie: " + (totalNewPriceTest))

        //inserting items and prices into arrays
         productsArray.push(rows[i]['ITEM'])
         priceArray.push(rows[i]['PRICE'])
         console.log("ARRAY " + productsArray)
         console.log("PRICE ARRAY " + priceArray)
        }
        console.log("inside productsStripe function.")
        console.log("overall prcie: " + totalNewPriceTest)
  
        totalNewPriceTest = parseFloat(totalNewPriceTest)
        var grandTotal = totalNewPriceTest;
        var finalGrandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal)
        console.log(parseFloat(finalGrandTotal))
  
      
        //stripe
                // loop over products array to construct the line_items
            const items = productsArray.map((product, i) => {
                return {
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'CAD',
                    product_data: {
                    name: product,
                    },
                    unit_amount: parseInt(priceArray[i], 10) * 100,
                },
                quantity: 1,
                };
            });
            
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                shipping_address_collection: {
                allowed_countries: ['CA'],
                },
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                line_items: items,
                mode: 'payment',
                success_url: 'https://floralfashionboutique.com/successPg',
                cancel_url: 'https://floralfashionboutique.com/catalogue',
            });
        console.log(session)
        res.json({ id: session.id });
        //console.log("customer id" + customer.id)
        console.log("totalNewPriceTest " + totalNewPriceTest)
  
      })
    })
  });
```

checkout.ejs (front end stripe script)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51HWim4ICsAKa9fJ8eYfD72iht4QeUi3sEGMtOvv6WNLyPYPVfq9Ke0EGc8rX6nSWSfB85c4uMpQ1doUbF9rGOlGx00XbnkKpee');
  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
  var total = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  var deliveryTotal = document.getElementById('deliveryRegionPrice');
  var userId = document.getElementById('sessionID');
  var delDate = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
  alert(delDate);
  var deliveryDate = delDate.value
  var totalVal = total.value;
  var totalWithDelivery = deliveryTotal.value;
  var sessionID = userId.value;

      //totalVal = totalVal.toFixed(2);

  alert(totalVal)
  
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Create a new Checkout Session using the server-side endpoint you
    // created in step 3.
    fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
    totalVal,
    totalWithDelivery,
    sessionID,
    deliveryDate,

    // name: 'gianluca',
    // userid: 123,
}),
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(session) {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
      // error, you should display the localized error message to your
      // customer using `error.message`.
      if (result.error) {
        alert(result.error.message);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please let me know if anyone can find what is wrong here. first time working with stripe :( thank you!

Comment: On first glance, there appear to be no glaring issues with your code. The fact that the Checkout UI shows correctly and redirects to the success URL also suggests that this isn't an integration issue. I would double check that you're using the right publishable and secret keys tied to your account: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys. If you're using test mode keys you need to ensure test mode is toggled on in the dashboard.

Comment: thank you.. appreciate your help. I actually wasn't looking at the test data. silly mistake. thanks :)